# How to throw an exception in a constructor?

Tags: f#

Doesn't it make sense if I do

```
type Point = 
    struct
        val Row: int
        val Column: int

        new (row, column) = if row >= 0 && column >= 0 then { Row = row; Column = column }
                            else failwith "Cooridinators must be non-negative!" 
        // This is not a valid object construction
        static member (+) (x: Point, y: Point) = Point (x.Row + y.Row, x.Column + y.Column)
        static member (-) (x: Point, y: Point) = Point (x.Row - y.Row, x.Column - y.Column)
        static member (*) (x: Point, a) = Point (x.Row * a, x.Column * a)
        static member (*) (a, x: Point) =  Point (x.Row * a, x.Column * a)
    end
```

If it was a class then maybe I can raise exception during the `do` binding, but in a structure there is no `do`, what am I supposed to do?

I figured out that it is possible to add another constructor after `failwith` to get around this, but it raises another question, how can I call the implicit constructor? Do I have to construct it explicitly first like

```
new () = { Row = 0; Column = 0} 
// Error structs auto supports a default constructor
```

If i simply do this using the default constructor

```
new (row, column) = if row >= 0 && column >= 0 then { Row = row; Column = column }
                    else
                        failwith "Cooridinators must be non-negative!"
                        new Point () // error
```

It appears to me that `Point ()` returns a unit rather than `Point`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the F# compiler complains because constructors should always have a structure:

> `new (` *patterns* `) =` *expressions* `{` *initialization* `} [then` *expressions* `]`

So, the part that initializes the fields cannot be nested under `if` or inside any other expression. You can throw exceptions either before the initialization or after (if you add `then` keyword). (This matters for classes with inheritance, but I don't think it makes any difference for structs.)

So, one way to write the code is to write:

```
type Point = 
    struct
        val Row: int
        val Column: int

        new (row, column) = 
          if row < 0 || column < 0 then failwith "Cooridinators must be non-negative!"
          { Row = row; Column = column }          

        // (Static members omitted)
    end
```

Note that I had to negate the condition, because you need to specify the case when *you want to throw* the exception (rather than saying when you can construct the object). The other alternative would be:

```
new (row, column) = 
  { Row = row; Column = column }          
  then if row < 0 || column < 0 then failwith "Cooridinators must be non-negative!"
```

Answer (score 4):

You have another alternative to throw exceptions in *initialization* section:

```
new (row, column) = 
  { Row = ((if row < 0 || column < 0 then failwith "Coordinators must be non-negative!"); row); 
    Column = column }
```

*Remember that validating struct constructors is not always a good idea*. As you found out, you cannot control initialization of default constructors. If it is a class, you can make sure all constructors are validated in the ways you want.

Answer (score 1):

It is an old question. However, none of the answers mentioned this: I think that idiomatic F# way is *not to throw an exception at all*! To achieve that you can use a `static member tryCreate`, which would return `Some Point` if all the conditions are fulfilled and `None` if something is wrong. Then you would follow the trail of option types to code your logic instead of dealing with exceptions! I also think that F# record is probably a more idiomatic way as well, unless you explicitly need struct for some very specific purpose.